# Yup conditional validation based on parent object schema

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I'm creating Yup validation schema with array().of method and I need to set some validation rules in that array based on value from outer schema object. How can I get reference to that value?

```js
const termsSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  termType: Yup.string().when('condition', {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.string()
      .required('Type is required'),
  }),
});

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  condition: Yup.boolean()
    .required('Error'),
  terms: Yup.array().of(termsSchema),
});
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's not possible, as [according to the documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema), `.when()` allows you to "Adjust the schema based on a sibling or sibling children fields."

Comment: `is: (value) => value == true.` you can use callback for `is` which gives access to `value` and you can use it however you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables from outside the Yup Schema can be access via a callback function using **when**. You can use any dummy field for the first parameter as the purpose was only to trigger the callback. Once condition is met, the validation rule after **then** would apply. For more information refer [Yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema).

```
let outside = true

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  dummy:Yup.string(),
  terms: Yup.array().of(termsSchema).when("dummy", {
    is: (value) => 
      outside === true,
      then: Yup.number().required("Please provide info")
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Quite sure you've already found a solution/workaround. However this approach may come in handy for people coming to this very question for a potential solution:

Since you need the values of sibling fields for a schema that is nested, you could create the nested schema using `when`, for example:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  condition: Yup.boolean()
    .required('Error'),
  terms: mixed().when('condition',(value) => {
     // use any logic you need to build/modify the returned schema
     return array().of(termsSchema)
 }),
});
```

Accessing nested fields using .when is a [current limitation](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/935) of yup, however this approach worked for me. I am also curious about what you did to solve this.